# run perl script with unknown perl location

Tags: shell-script, osx, perl, executable, shebang

I'm developing a perl script which expected to be downloaded by Mac users with a very small knowledge of shell, linux etc, let's say office managers and accountants.

After the downloading the script should be executed just by double-clicking via GUI.

My goal is to make this as painless as possible to non-tech-savvy user.

My doubts are:

- after the downloading the script won't have the executable bit
- if the perl executable is not at the default location then I should write something instead of `#!/usr/bin/perl`. What should I write there? Is there any other way except open a console and type `perl ./script.pl` ?

Comment: Does `env` come standard on OSX?  If so, you could use `#!/usr/bin/env perl` which searches the path to find the perl executable.

Comment: See [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Comment: @John1024, yes - `env` comes standard with OSX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or, you can have `sh` take care of it for you:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 exec perl -x "$0" "$@"

 #!/usr/bin/perl
 ...
```

Yes, that's `sh` and Perl all in one file.

From `man perlrun`:

> **-x**
>    tells Perl that the program is embedded in a larger chunk of
>               unrelated text, such as in a mail message.  Leading garbage will
>               be discarded until the first line that starts with "#!" and
>               contains the string "perl".  Any meaningful switches on that line
>               will be applied.

This approach only assumes the path of `sh` (which should be the same on any POSIX-compliant OS) and that a non-interactive instance of `sh` has `perl` somewhere in its `PATH`.

As for ensuring the script has the executable bit set, you can always distribute it as a tarball and have your users "right click, extract here" from the GUI. If the tarball contained the script with the executable bit set, the extracted script should have the executable bit set.

Comment: Note that POSIX doesn't specify the path of `sh`. `/bin/sh` may also  be a Bourne shell (not on OS/X though) where that syntax should also work except in very old versions where  you need `${1+"$@"}` instead of `"$@"` (`${1+"$@"}` will also work in POSIX shells, but not in some old versions of `zsh` (`/bin/sh` was `zsh` on OS/X at some point)).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas "POSIX doesn't specify the path of `sh`". That's very weird. Thanks for the info, though.

Answer (score 6):

For the shebang line, use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

`env` will search the PATH at execute the first `perl` that it finds.  If you want to specify any options for perl, just add them to the end of the line above.

If more than one `perl` is installed, `env` will run the first one it finds in PATH.